# Combine multiple csv files time based visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I have multiple csv files, with the same headers and in the same folder. My goal is to combine all the csv files using visual basic (vb.net) based on certain time.
I am using data logger that can log every 15 minutes. So, 1 file csv for 15 minutes logging, 2 files csv for 30 minutes logging, and so on.
I want to combine all of those csv files in one day (from 14.00 on day 1 to 13.59 on day 2) automatically with the file names based on the time.

For example :

Flowdata20170427220000.csv (27-04-2017 22:00:00)

```
Name,Attribute1,Attribute2,Attribute3
name1,111,abc,zzz
name2,222,def,yyy
```

Flowdata20170427221500.csv (27-04-2017 22:15:00)

```
Name,Attribute1,Attribute2,Attribute3
name3,333,ghi,xxx
name4,444,jkl,www
```

and so on until

Flowdata20170428214500.csv (28-04-2017 21:35:00)

```
Name,Attribute1,Attribute2,Attribute3
name5,555,mno,vvv
name6,666,pqr,uuu
```

and the final file is :

Flowdata20170427-20170428.csv

```
Name,Attribute1,Attribute2,Attribute3
name1,111,abc,zzz
name2,222,def,yyy
name3,333,ghi,xxx
name4,444,jkl,www
...,...,...,...
...,...,...,...
name5,555,mno,vvv
name6,666,pqr,uuu
```

Can you help me out please? Searching in google but nothing helps me.

Comment: Smells like a homework :-) A hint: try using the streamreader and streamwriter class.

Comment: Do you have any existing code that you have to start with? If so it would be worth posting it with your data samples

Comment: Why not write the data to the 15 minute files **and** a second "all" file so they dont have to be combined?